# Using a custom image marker on google static map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

how to have custom image marker on google static map, i need url format:

this is what i have tried, but its having default marker image
    http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=25.3176452,82.97391440000001,&zoom=15&markers=25.3176452,82.97391440000001|25.3176452,82.97391440000001&path=color:0x0000FF80|weight:5|25.3176452,82.97391440000001&size=175x175&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE

Answer (score 55):

**This is what you want:**

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=17&size=512x512&maptype=hybrid&markers=icon:http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico|34.052230,-118.243680

for a custom image, put the `icon:url` after of `markers`...

**Format**

```
icon:url|lat,lng
```

**Example**

```
icon:http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico|34.052230,-118.243680
```

**a result of my example**

[image: stackoverflow server ubication...]

For more information check google maps api, there are more information like size, markers position, center map, map type... etc.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#MapTypes

*If the icon, img, don't appear it will be the size of image, try with another size,less than 64x64 px, format of image, "GIF, JPEG and PNG", the documentation recommend "PNG", if it doesn't appear check permision of image for public request(external request)...

Comment: @PhilAndrews The docs says inline-defined SVG paths work, though.

Comment: is there a way to customize the height and width of that image in the url?

Comment: @caffeinescript yes, if you see in the url, of the api, there is an option of `size=512x512` width and height, in the url of api, search for size

Comment: @DarckBlezzer i think thats the height and width of the image not the icon image no? I also saw that the max size is 64 * 64 on their docs

Comment: @DarckBlezzer Is there a way to pass icon size?

Comment: Absolutely brillant.

Comment: 2018, SVG's still do not work (tested with file url, not an inline path).

Comment: And just try to make the icon url simplified.
like this 
https://siteurl/images/marker.png
not like this
https://siteurl/somedirectory/another/inner/marker.png

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#CustomIcons) you can specify custom icons like so:

`markers=icon:...`

e.g. amending your URL:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=25.3176452,82.97391440000001,&zoom=15&markers=icon:http://www.megaadresse.com/images/icons/google-maps.png|25.3176452,82.97391440000001&path=color:0x0000FF80|weight:5|25.3176452,82.97391440000001&size=175x175

Gives you:

[image]

PS: the `sensor` parameter is no longer required.

PPS: also you seemed to have specified the same coordinates twice in your markers parameter, so it was actually drawing two markers on the same location.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an image in the marker:

```
var campaign_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("campaign_map_canvas"), mapOptions);


    var selected_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: campaign_map,
        icon: 'path/to/image'
    });

google.maps.event.trigger(campaign_map,'resize');
```

**EDIT**
You can use the following:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=480x480&markers=icon:path/to/image.png%257C996600%7Carea/you/want/
```

Comment: That's using the JS API, not the Static Maps (the question was really mis-tagged, I've amended it)

Comment: Google maps is mainly JS? What exactly are you looking to do then?

Comment: The OP is referring to this API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: I resized the png icon to 64*64,, and tested this
&markers=icon:path/to/image.png,,,, dunno its not working,, any idea ?? and what is this ?

%257C996600%7Carea/you/want/ ??

Answer (score 0):

You must use a valid format. Taken from the official documentation:

> Icon images may be in PNG, JPEG or GIF formats, though PNG is recommended