# Google static maps SVG marker

Tags: google-maps, svg

I am trying to use an SVG (several paths) as a marker for a Google static map. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492733/using-a-custom-image-marker-on-google-static-map) seemed to suggest that an SVG path is possible but I cannot see any example in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#CustomIcons).

Is it possible to use an SVG (either via a URL or with the SVG path), or shall I just stick to a transparent PNG?

Comment: If you intend to place a bunch of svg symbols/shapes in the Google Map you can create an svg overlay and call the symbols/shapes from an .svg or .xml  file. I have an example online at : http://svgDiscovery.com/UUgleMap/svgOverlay.htm

Comment: I do just want to use one marker, but actually, adding a SVG over the top of the map is a pretty good solution. Thank you

Comment: Why the downvote? Just because it's not documented, doesn't mean it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#CustomIcons) you link to:

> Icon format:
>
> - Icon images may be in PNG, JPEG or GIF formats, though PNG is recommended.
> - Icons may be up to 4096 pixels maximum size (64x64 for square images).

SVG icons are not documented as being an available format.